# Is there a way to hide the QuickType bar in iOS 8 WITHOUT disabling autocorrect?

Tags: ios, ios8, autocorrect, quicktypebar

I want to keep autocorrect, but the QuickType bar obstructs screens in my app and I'd like to disable it or at least make it hidden by default.

Answer (score 1):

Currently no.  Apple likes to give those kind of setting to the user; not developers.  If you really need it off, you would have to design/create a [Custom Keyboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html).